# UIScrollView and a background Image

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a UIViewContainer having a View1-->ScrollView-->View2-->Imageview(background Image)

The scrollview is placed below the top layout guide so that the screen doesnt scroll under the battery etc. Because of this the top layout guide is blank/Blue(view's color,no background image).

So I added another Imageview to View1 to act as a background, but then the scrollview scrolling stops. This is all done on the storyboard.!

You can see the screenshots here 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yHQL.jpg

Comment: You should add UIView programmatically. Do not add it through IB. and Set ContentSize of Scroll View Properly

Comment: Please show us some screenshots of the constraints that you add to your views.

Comment: I have the following constraints: ScrollView: Pinned height and width and 4 sides and similar with the subview: height, width and all 4 sides. The link has the screenshot of the constraints http://imgur.com/04RNJyt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the way i was using Autolayout with my scroll view. I removed all the constraints and added the constraints as explained in the link below. Resolved my problem
http://blog.surecase.eu/working-with-uiscrollview-in-storyboard-using-autolayout/